# Фильтр\обработчик альбомов Вконтакте

Tags: веб-программирование, javascript, клиент, вконтакте

В общем, есть такая задача:
Дан произвольный альбом Вконтакте какого-нибудь паблика или группы. Необходимо проанализировать этот альбом так, чтобы "выдать" фото (или ссылки на фото, или еще как-нибудь), загруженные людьми из определенного города.

P.S. Сам работаю на С и то новичок-стажер, а с вебом только не сталкивался:) Подскажите, как лучше реализовать задачу? Можно ли это сделать скриптом и на чем или надо писать клиент для Вконтакте? Подскажите, где копать...

Спасибо!

Comment: [вконтакте api][1]


  [1]: http://vk.com/pages?oid=-1&p=%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 1):

1. Метод [`photos.get()`](https://vk.com/dev/photos.get) вернёт список фотографий альбома, у каждой поле owner_id — id загрузившего. Меньше 0 – группа/сообщество, больше 0 – человек.
2. Положительные id в метод [`users.get()`](https://vk.com/dev/users.get), где в `fields` указать доп. поле "city" — вернёт список пользователей с указанным для каждого городом.

Попробовать этим методы можно прямо на странице документации. Эти же запросы можно выполнять, например, через [Javascript SDK](https://vk.com/dev/Javascript_SDK).

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что забить какой-нибудь код в строке браузера не получится? Ведь, насколько я понял, надо обращаться к серверу за инфой о пользователе, загрузившем фото, или нет?

Comment: Тут два шага: получить список фотографий с авторами, и потом получить инфу об этих пользователях (сразу о нескольких, max 1000 за один запрос). Т.е. хорошо бы на писать несколько строчек кода: выполнить один запрос, разобрать ответ, выполнить второй запрос.

Но у ВК API есть замечательный метод [`execute()`](https://vk.com/dev/execute), которому передаётся скрипт (синтакс JS), который целиком выполняется на стороне ВК и возвращает результат. Т.е. технически можно написать этот скрипт, и передать его через `execute()`, и всё это будет выглядеть одной длинной строкой в браузере.